# How to secure App.Config windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, security

i've a windows form application that i would like to try to sell.

In order to work the application needs an ApiKey and ApiSecret generated from an online API service X.

The idea i've thinked is that:

People that want to buy the application, register on my website, insert there their personal details, including ONLY the ApiKey previously generated from service X.

As soon as i receive their data and payment, i create a personal version of the software that has the ApiKey builtin inside the App.config of the program and i send them the compiled version of it (.exe).

Once they receive their program, they will insert the ApiSecret and use it, ApiSecret will be saved in App.Config and will let users access the service API only if both match.

Is this kind of reasoning good for this kind of application?

What i also want is ApiKey to be Integrity safe: I don't want people that have a version of the program, to be able to change the ApiKey and pass it to other people that haven't payed for the service.

(should i use encryption?, If yes, How?),

I think that ApiSecret once saved by the user, should be encrypted too, in order to avoid people that find a version of the program to access the service of the users that buyed app without auth.

How can i guarantee this properties? And Moreover, I'm making all this problem, because i've read that it's possible to access portions of App.Config from .exe file, is that a real possibility?

The app also has a database, should i encrypt the connectionstring in App.config too?

Comment: Everything you store in your application can be revealed by a motivated reverse engineer.

Comment: I know that, but i want to try to avoid to make him things too easy. I know that i can use obfuscators, that should make things a lot more diffult for him. But with this kind of app performance are more important, so can't rely on them

Comment: If you send the key embeeded in **any** way, you've already lost, a motivated user will be able to crack your program. Not only that, but they'll also be able to copy from computer to computer and use at will, with you ever selling out a single copy. I would keep the key private in your own server and make the program just a client of that, and your server make the API call itself. That way access control is entirely upon you.

Comment: For calling an API I would provide a method for users to generate (via the app or website) a signed token based on a key and secret. The application should authenticate via token so that revocation is possible. I would not have the application connect directly to a database, but rather force all calls through an API. There's no foolproof way of encrypting a database connection string if it's in the hands of your users.

Comment: So maybe the best way to proceed is create a webserver, let users authenticate to it via winform app, then ask in windows form app if ApiKey of the User logged in is right, and finally let them use the program by setting up their ApiSecret?

Comment: If you are going to create a "personal" version of the software and have them log into your web server, then using a self-signed certificate (i.e., one that you create on your server using your own certificate authority and ship with the personal version) may provide a solution.  I'm not skilled enough to whip up a "back of the napkin" solution to this problem, but I suspect there's a solution using something like this.